# Format array of numbers as currency with minimum width between values

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

I have some lists of floats:

```
arr1 = [ 123456.78, 123.45, -123456789.01, 23.45 ]
arr2 = [ .1278, .92, .5401, .2345 ]
```

I want to print them in tabular form with various formats, depending on which list of values I'm printing

Eg:

- print `arr1` as whole dollar values with thousands separators
- print `arr2` as percentages with 1 decimal place

Would result in something such as:

```
"       $123,457 |            $123 |   -$123,456,789 |             $23"
"          12.8% |           92.0% |           54.0% |           23.4%"
```

This is what I have been able to come up with so far:

```
def join(fmt, arr):
    return ' | '.join([fmt.format(a) for a in arr])

print('{}'.format(join('${:14,.0f}', arr1)))
print('{}'.format(join('{:15.1%}',   arr2)))
```

This results in the following:

```
"$       123,457 | $           123 | $  -123,456,789 | $            23"
"          12.8% |           92.0% |           54.0% |           23.4%"
```

Issues with this approach:

- It prints the dollar sign first, and then the padding
- It prints the negative sign after the dollar sign
- Since the dollar sign is not part of the formatting, I have to remember to reduce my padding from 15 to 14 for that format string.

How can I get the dollar sign printed up against the number?
Is it possible to make the dollar sign part of the format so that I can still use 15 as my padding?

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.currency

Comment: @PM2Ring how would I use `locale.currency` in my `join` function, or would I have to special case the printing of currencies?

Comment: Yes, you will need to treat the currencies as a special case. Another option to using `locale` is to do the formatting in 2 stages. First format the number and add the currency symbol, and possible negative sign. Then do the padding. This is a little more compact if you can use Python 3.6+ f-strings.

Comment: @PM2Ring additionally I am not sure I can drop the cents in the values? (ie: print only the dollar value)

Comment: @PM2Ring I am using python 3.6.5

Comment: In that case, you'll have to do it "manually" in 2 stages, since `locale.currency` doesn't give you an option to not print cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to format the money values as whole dollars, using Python 3.6 [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals). We *could* also do the padding with `.rjust` in the `dollars` function, but it's cleaner & more flexible to do it separately.

```
arr1 = [123456.78, 123.45, -123456789.01, 23.45]

def dollars(n):
    return f"{'-' if n < 0 else ''}${round(abs(n)):,}"

s = ' | '.join([dollars(u).rjust(15) for u in arr1])
print(repr(s))
```

**output**

```
'       $123,457 |            $123 |   -$123,456,789 |             $23'
```

Make sure that `round(abs(n))` does what you want. The `round` function does ["Banker's rounding"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even), and you may wish to use `int(0.5 + x)` instead of `round(x)`. Also consider the effect of taking the absolute value after rounding instead of before.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you:

```
dollar_commas = ''.join("${:,} | ".format(int(round(num))).rjust(20) for num in arr1).replace('$-', '-$')
print dollar_commas[:-2]

percent = ''.join("{0:.1%} | ".format(num).rjust(20) for num in arr2)
print percent[:-2]
```

Output:

```
     $123,457 |              $123 |     -$123,456,789 |               $23
        12.8% |             92.0% |             54.0% |             23.4%
```